# Store fixed value in variable

Tags: pine-script

I'm programming a percentage-based trailing stop in Pinescript V5. There are existing scripts that calculate the proper stop value using `close` and the chosen percentage, in this example called `trailing_sl_percent`:

```
Long_TSLPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
stopValue = close * (1 - trailing_sl_percent)
math.max(stopValue, Long_TSLPrice [1])
else
0
```

Let's say you buy a stock at 100,00 USD and you want the trailing stop loss to be at 1%. In this case, `stopValue` should be at 101,00 USD. In Pinescript, the price that you bought your stock at is stored in the variable `strategy.position_avg_price`.

Now the problem: The above code doesn't calculate `stopValue` from `strategy.position_avg_price` but from `close`. This means, your trailing stop loss level is higher or lower than actually planned.

My solution would be to store the difference between `strategy.position_avg_price` and `close` in a variable called `offset` by using this code:

```
offset = strategy.position_avg_price - close
```

Unfortunately, the correct value for `offset` is calculated only once, directly after filling the order. Is there a way to only store this first calculation as a fixed value that I can then add to the formula to calculate `stopValue`? This would look something like this:

```
stopValue = (close - offset) * (1 - trailing_sl_percent)
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to detect position opened event and store the `offset` value only in that moment:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

isLongPositionOpened() =>
    strategy.position_size[1] <= 0 and strategy.position_size > 0

isShortPositionOpened() =>
    strategy.position_size[1] >= 0 and strategy.position_size < 0

isPositionOpened() =>
    isLongPositionOpened() or isShortPositionOpened()

var float offset = na
if isPositionOpened()
    offset := strategy.position_avg_price - close
plot(offset)
```